# select generated ellipse in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, ellipse, generated

I would like to get the name of a selected ellpise.

This is my c# code: (code behind)

```
private StackPanel generateSensorObject(int tempvalue, int diameter, string moduletype, string modulename, string macaddress, string lastdate, string description)
    {
        StackPanel s1 = new StackPanel();
        Viewbox v1 = new Viewbox();
        Grid g1 = new Grid();
        ToolTip tool1 = new ToolTip();
        StackPanel st1 = new StackPanel();
        TextBlock tool1t1 = new TextBlock();
        TextBlock tool1t2 = new TextBlock();
        TextBlock tool1t3 = new TextBlock();
        TextBlock tool1t4 = new TextBlock();
        Button b1 = new Button();
        ContextMenu m1 = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem();

        Ellipse e1 = new Ellipse();
        e1.Height = e1.Width = diameter;

        tool1t1.Text = "MAC Addresse: " + macaddress;
        tool1t2.Text = "Typ: " + moduletype;
        tool1t3.Text = "letzter Wert eingetroffen: " + lastdate;
        tool1t4.Text = "Beschreibung: " + description;

        b1.Content = "Diagramm";

        st1.Children.Add(tool1t1);
        st1.Children.Add(tool1t2);
        st1.Children.Add(tool1t3);
        st1.Children.Add(tool1t4);
        st1.Children.Add(b1);
        tool1.Content = st1;

        TextBlock t1 = new TextBlock();
        TextBlock t2 = new TextBlock();
        t1.Text = modulename;
        t2.Text = tempvalue.ToString();
        t2.ToolTip = tool1;
        tool1.StaysOpen = true;

        g1.Children.Add(e1);
        s1.Children.Add(t1);
        g1.Children.Add(t2);
        t2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        t2.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
        s1.MouseRightButtonUp += ButtonDiagramm_Click;
        v1.Child = g1;
        s1.Children.Add(v1);

        return s1;
    }
```

This is my methode to generate the ellpises.

Now I am trying to get the name of a selected ellipse on the canvas with the ButtonDiagram methode. But I don't know how to do that.

Does anybody know the trick?
Thanks!

Comment: Define "selected ellipse". Do you mean _"with the `ButtonDiagramm_Click()` method"_? If so, why are you subscribing to the `StackPanel`'s `Click` event? Why not to each `Ellipse` object's event? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, along with a precise, complete description of what that code does and how it's different from what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to the `RoutedEventArgs.Source` property, if your mouse rights click on some ellipse, it should be passed in there:

```
void ButtonDiagramm_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
   var ellipse = e.Source as Ellipse;
   if(ellipse != null){
      //do everything with ellipse here, not just access its Name
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment. This is a good tip. But my main problem is to get a specific name of an ellipse which I rightclick on the canvas. If I try to get the name with `var ellipse = e.Source as Ellipse; ellipse.Name;`. It's not correct...

Comment: @JohannesSchlüter what you say does not make sense. Suppose your Canvas has many ellipses, clicking anywhere on it cannot determine which one is clicked. If you mean you just need to get the name of the only ellipse you added to your Canvas. Then that also against does not make sense. Why don't you store it somewhere else? Searching it each time (even when clicking out of it) is not the right way to go.

Comment: Damn. Yes you're right. It's clear now. I'm going to solve the problem now on a different way, but thanks for trying to help me anyway. :)